# How to tell Angular route prevent some routes?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I have two angular app, one of them is the home page of my application and other things about the website *(such as privacy policy, docs, login and signup forms)*, but I also have my **admin panel** which is another application.

Here is the directory structure:

```
firstapp.html (my first app)
init.js
controller/...
views/....
panel
    |---controllers/...
    |---views/...
    |--panel.html
    |--init.js
```

in `firstapp.html`, I have my landing pages, documents and etc, and in `panel` directory I have another completely different app for my administrator panel which is obviously another app!

in my **firstapp** `init.js` I have:

```
angularApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "./view/home.html?v=" + $config.app_version,
            controller: "HomeController"
        })
        .when("/register/:page", {
            templateUrl: "./view/register.html?v=" + $config.app_version,
            controller: "RegisterController"
        })
});
```

and when I login to see my panel directory, my firstapp route does not allow me to see my other app (panel.html), and it still thinks the firstapp should handle it.

Any idea?

Comment: I think it is handled automatically, it will just let the Angular to get those locations that are defined, and you even did not use "otherwise" for your router. I think you're fine to go :) Check your panel page, maybe there is a problem there